# jQuery: Prevent Remote Rails Form Submit with Live()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a form in jQuery that is submitted remotely:

```
<%= form_for @order, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

On the client I am binding to the form submit event (in coffee script):

```
 $('#new_order').live 'submit', (e) ->
```

and I want to prevent the rails remote form submit but I can't seem to get it working, I've tried:

```
 e.preventDefault()
 e.stopPropagation()
 return false
```

None of these seemed to work. I'm fairly new to Rails so I was wondering if I was missing something about the remote submit handler?

EDIT:

I've found that it works if I use `bind` instead of `live`

Comment: Maybe you should bind your custom actions to the form button `click` event, instead of the `submit` one. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is that live cannot reliably preventDefault actions bound earlier in the document:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

> Calling event.stopPropagation() in the event handler is ineffective
>   in stopping event handlers attached lower in the document; the event
>   has already propagated to document."

Using:

```
 $('#new_order').on 'submit', (e) ->
```

does the trick!

Comment: Ran into this problem on some older legacy code and switching to `on` worked like a charm :D